How to calculate a dual $T^*$ given a member $T$ of $\textrm{SE}(3)$?
In reproducing "A Linear-Time Variational Integrator...", I encountered the undefined symbol ${T^k}^*$ in equations 16a and 16b. A professional acquaintance proved to me that ${T^k}^*$ is a dual of ${T^k}\in{\textrm{SE}(3)}$. This makes intuitive sense to me, a physicist, as ${T^k}^*$ is a kind of directional derivative and the term in which it appears is an application of d'Alembert's Principle to external or control forces.
All that still leaves me with a computational problem. I know how to represent ${T^k}\in{\textrm{SE}(3)}$ as a matrix, say,
$$
T^k = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{R} & \mathbf{x} \\
0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\mathbf{R}\in\mathrm{SO}(3)$ is an ordinary rotation matrix, and $\mathbf{x}=[x,y,z]^{\intercal}\in\mathbb{R}^3$ is a displacement vector (column vector).
I need a concrete representation of ${T^k}^*$ given a concrete representation of $T^k$ so I can write computer programs (say in Mathematica) that mechanize equations 16b and 16c.
I'm confused and stuck. I'd be grateful for any advice, corrections, or other critique. Here are some of the dead ends I've walked down.
EDIT: After sleeping on it, I think I see a way forward.

Find the parameterization of $\mathrm{SE}(3)$ in which the target of the directional derivative expression ${T^k}^* P(V)$ namely, $P(V)$, is expressed.
Express $T^k$ (no star) in that parameterization, read off its components.
Write ${T^k}^*$ as empty partial derivatives with respect to those parameters and multiply them by the components from #2, dot-product-wise.
Apply the operator ${T^k}^*$ to the target, $P(V)$, symbolically.
You now have an expression for the whole application, ${T^k}^* P(V)$.

Does this sound right?

Looking at this paper, and the two papers it references [11,16], this is what I can gather. Firstly, the notation is very confusing - it seems the term ${T^k}^*P(T^k)$ should actually be something like ${T^k}^* \partial_T P(T^k)$ (see for example equation (11a) in reference [11]), meaning it is the element of $\mathfrak{se}(3)^*$ defined by
$$
V\in\mathfrak{se}(3) \mapsto (d_{T^k}P) (T^kV) := \frac{d}{ds}\Bigg\vert_{s=0}P(T^k\gamma_V(s))
$$
where $\gamma_V(s)$ is any curve in $\operatorname{SE}(3)$ with $\gamma_V(0) = e, \gamma_V'(0) = V$ (for example, $\gamma_V(s) = \exp_{\operatorname{SE}(3)}(sV)$). In other words, the asterisk implies "pull-back" ($g^*f = f\circ g$). The second confusing thing about the notation is that there is an implicit identification of $\mathfrak{se}(3)^*$ with $\mathfrak{se}(3)\simeq \mathbb{R}^6$, and so you would like to actually interpret the above element of $\mathfrak{se}(3)^*$ as an element of $\mathbb{R}^6$, in other words, to find an element $W\in\mathbb{R}^6$ such that
$$
W\cdot V = \frac{d}{ds}\Bigg\vert_{s=0}P(T^k\gamma_V(s)) \qquad\forall{V\in\mathbb{R}^6},
$$
where $\cdot$ denotes the usual dot product in $\mathbb{R}^6$. If you have a parametrization of $\operatorname{SE}(3)$ already in mind, you could calculate wrt that. If not, probably the most natural parametrization is via the exponential map
$$
\exp_{\operatorname{SE}(3)}:\mathfrak{se}(3) \mapsto \operatorname{SE}(3)
$$
(which is surjective, though not injective). You can find explicit expressions for this in many places, e.g. A tutorial on SE(3) transformation parameterizations and on-manifold optimization, equations (9.23-24).
Then taking $T^k = \exp_{\operatorname{SE}(3)}(U)$, say, it's straightforward (but tedious) to calculate
$$
\frac{d}{ds}\Bigg\vert_{s=0}\exp_{\operatorname{SE}(3)}(U)\exp_{\operatorname{SE}(3)}(sV)
$$
and from this
$$
\frac{d}{ds}\Bigg\vert_{s=0} P(\exp_{\operatorname{SE}(3)}(U)\exp_{\operatorname{SE}(3)}(sV)) = \sum_{ij}\frac{\partial P}{\partial x_{ij}}(\exp_{\operatorname{SE}(3)}(U)) \frac{d}{ds}\Bigg\vert_{s=0}\left(\exp_{\operatorname{SE}(3)}(U)\exp_{\operatorname{SE}(3)}(sV)\right)_{ij}$$
The above is actually just
$$
d_e [\exp_{\operatorname{SE}(3)}(U)](V),
$$
which in general is given by the expression (3) here, and is calculated explicitly for $\operatorname{SE}(3)$ in this MSE answer, for example (though I haven't checked whether it's correct there).

There are many great leads here for me to learn from, and it might be everything I need for practical purposes. In particular, I found reference 11 impenetrable, but by focusing me on equation 11a, you gave me a way to work backwards, and that's great. I'm grateful.

Ok, hope it was helpful. As another data point, the equations are also in reference [16], namely the two equations right after equation (7). The term you're concerned with corresponds to the $\frac{\Delta t}{2}\nabla_gL_i$ part, where the group element $g\in G$ corresponds to $T\in \operatorname{SE}(3)$. Since the kinetic part of the Lagrangian doesn't depend on the group element, $\nabla_gL_i$ equals $\nabla_TP$. The definition of this is given at the top of page 1093 (although missing an evaluation at $s=0$), and you'll see it corresponds to my definition above.

you might be amused to see how far I got in this so far ... everything up to but not including the term in question. I'm gearing up for another attack. https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3103170

Cool. I'm a bit busy atm to look at this properly, but will be freer in a week or two. I'll take a look then and see if I can write down something more explicit that will be useful to you (if you haven't figured it out yourself).

I found this "screw theory" that might be relevant, too https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw_theory. I appreciate your kind attention, too, it should not go without saying.

A more stable URL for "A tutorial on SE(3) transformations ..." is perhaps https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.15980 .

in retrospect, your answer is the only sensible one. The undefined term is in a position where "virtual work" pursuant to D'Alembert's Principle must go. That term must have dimensions of "generalized displacement" times "generalized force." Generalized force can be the derivative of a potential like $P(T)$. Generalized displacement is represented by $T^k$, whose dual is ${T^k}^*$. I'm in the process of writing up a new discrete geometric variational integrator based on your answer and on Equations 16b and 16c above. It'll take me a while (nights & weekends). I'll post here when done.
